# Difference between abstract class and interface in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

One of the most frequently asked questions on iOS developer interview is - difference between abstract classed and interface.

I don't know an answer and i don't get it neither. Interface is a section of class, when you declared methods. it could be open for other classes (public, .h file) or hidden in implementation.

Abstract class is a class, that is only used to create hidden subclasses and it should not have own init methods (if i understand correct).

So, what exactly is answer for that question? And what does that question mean?

I did spend time searching for an answers, but answers wasn't related to Obj-C, so i can't figure out by myself.

I hope someone could provide clear answer and that question would be helpful for those guys, who want to pass an interview.

Comment: The exact anwser is: ObjectiveC doesn't have abstract classes...

Comment: From apple.developer.com - Class clusters group a number of private concrete subclasses under a public abstract superclass. The grouping of classes in this way simplifies the publicly visible architecture of an object-oriented framework without reducing its functional richness. Class clusters are based on the Abstract Factory design pattern.

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban They are abstract in concept, not abstract in functionality. Objective-C has no support for true abstract classes like, for example, Java.

Comment: @rmaddy. well, yes, i just post a question i've been asked passing an interview on a position of middle iOS dev. Obviously, i couldnt answer it

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban "I can't answer that because ObjC doesn't have abstract classes" is exactly the right answer :D ("And perhaps I'm interviewing for the wrong job? You did ask for a Cocoa dev, right?")

Comment: Side note: while it's not possible to enforce this during compile time, it is (amazingly) possible to enforce it at `+load` time (prior to most code execution). Nick Lockwood recently demonstrated a technique. https://github.com/nicklockwood/MustOverride. This is a bit crazy, and very uncommon to actually do, but a very interesting and enlightening achievement.

Comment: @rmaddy just iOS dev vacation ;) Maybe they want me to tell about abstract pattern, which imply that using class like NSNumber you getting primitive number values (actually private classes of NSNumber).  That is what i get from developer.apple.com - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassClusters/ClassClusters.html

Comment: @RobNapier that quite exciting, thank you for that link!

Comment: @RobNapier What's wrong with *saying*: interface is an abstract class— only to its `.m` file. Inside the `.m` we implement all the methods wrote in our interface? I mean if the `.m` file doesn't implement a method already declared in the its private abstract class (aka interface) it will give a compiler error as you promised to do implement something but didn't...Other than that yes abstract classes and interface are very different. Or is it that the difference of the 'interface only being applicable to a single implementation file' that which makes the diff of abstract class and interface?

Comment: @Honey Interfaces are not abstract classes. Abstract classes should never be instantiated; only their subclasses are intended to be. The `.h` defines a class, but it's not abstract. You're certainly intended to creates instances of that type. In your example, until an implementation is provided, the class cannot be compiled at all. Abstract classes (in C++/Java/etc) can absolutely be compiled without implementations of all their pieces. They just can't be instantiated. So what you're describing is different in intent and in mechanics.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

A good way to approach this problem is first think about it in general programming theory, and then in more concrete Objective-C context.

---

**Abstract Class** - is a class intended purely for subclassing, one must not instantiate it. Abstract class declares something and has also the implementation for that.

What is the reason for having such special class? It is modelled after real life! :) 
Imagine an abstraction - an animal. What has **each** animal in common? They are all **alive** (and can die). They need to **eat**. The can **move** in space. These traits are common and **fundamental** to all animals. I heaven't heard about an animal that doesn't needs food, cannot move and lives forever. Other then that there is a LOT of **not so fundamental** differences between various animals.

There is **no animal** on the planet which is **purely an abstract animal** like that. That set of fundamental behaviours, traits is simply not enough to be a concrete animal.. 
There is an implied principle, that to be a concrete animal, you have to have some **additional** traits besides those fundamental ones.

Now, in programming, we need to be able to somehow

- express these fundamentals (interface **declaration**)
- have a way of describing how they work (**implementation**)
- attribute them to a class
- prevent instantiation
- ensure that any concrete animal will have them (**inheritance**)

We know, what these fundamentals are (declared public interface) and we know in practice how they manifest themselves concretely (implementation of those declared traits). We want them to be inherited by all concrete entities. So we do it in the abstract class because it satisfies these condition I mentioned. It contains all the fundamentals, has their implementation, but cannot be instantiated on its own.

*Abstract class is an abstraction over a set of related entities that captures what is fundamentally common between all of them., tells us how it is done..and ensures all more concrete entities will inherit this.*

---

**Interface** - is something less. Let's a have a real life analogy. Person, robot, animal, wind (a force of nature).
Some people can **sing**. A robot has a voice synthesizer module embedded so it can **sing**. The autumn wind touching my teracce glass "sings" a lot I can tell you. And Tinka (r.i.p) my dog, was actually a good singer too.

But really, "singing" between these four has the only thing in common - you can hear it as pleasing sound in your ears. How the singing happens for those four, differs **a lot** in reality. (implementation)

Another complication is, certainly not all people, dogs, winds, or animals can sing. **Some** of them can.

So how would we reflect this situation in programming? Via interface :)

You can have an interface called `"SingInterface"` which in our case has one behaviour/trait/functionality declared and it is `sing`. Interface simply declares something and that's it. Interface doesn't say how that something is done, there is no concrete implementation. Nor does it say who can do it, the trait in the interface is not limited to one type or one class really. (see http://www.nasa.gov/centers/goddard/universe/black_hole_sound.html)

*Interface is a list of 1 to N traits/functionalities without knowing how concretely will they be realized, and that list of traits/functionalities that can be arbitrarily (no rules exist to who) attributable to entities from disparate sets that are fundamentally different (animals or robots).*

Object oriented programming borrows many concepts from real life. That's why these analogies work so well.

---

**In Objective C**, contrary to some other languages (C# etc),

there is no language level support for **abstract classes**. It is **not possible** to enforce that a class is abstract during compilation. A class is abstract only by convention and respecting that convention by developers.

As for interfaces, a word "protocol" is used in objective C. It's just a different word for the same thing.

In objective C you can

- **code against the interface** ..by declaring some object as

  ```
   id<protocolName>
  ```
- **add additional functionality to classes** by declaring that they conform to protocol which you do in the class interface

  ```
  @interface ClassName <protocolName>
  ```

So, there might possibly be even a case where your class is a subclass of abstract class, and it also conform to some protocol.

Comment: Thats some neat answer!

Comment: @Earl Grey thats awesome one! Btw, you should try to write a book, i would love it definitely.

Comment: This answer deserves many more votes! I did my part! :-) Awesomely explained!

Comment: Very clean explanation of the concept ! +1

Comment: What's wrong with saying: interface is an abstract class— **only** to its `.m` file . Inside the `.m` we implement all the public methods wrote in our interface? I mean if the `.m` file doesn't implement a method already declared in the its private abstract class (aka interface) it will not give a compiler error as something you promised to implement but didn't...Other than that yes abstract classes and interface are very different. Or is it that the difference of the 'interface only being applicable to a *single* implementation file' that which makes the diff of abstract class and interface?

Comment: I would not mix programming concepts with file structure. it is simply not the same thing.

Comment: thanks a lot for your efforts , clear example for concept

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Rob Napier's comment at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28726170/difference-between-abstract-class-and-interface-in-objective-c?noredirect=1#comment70813049_28726170). My answer is:

An interface is just the outside view of a class. What it reveals *publicly*.

In Swift you just write a class in a single `.Swift` file, and if ask Xcode to show you can [generate its interface](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1914/_index.html). Xcode will **only** then show properties/functions that are public/internal.

In Objective-C. You first have to **manually** write the interface...declaring what of the class is public and then manually write the implementation. An interface without implementation is **not** compilable. It's like you saying this is how my class will look like, but then you have provided nothing for **how it implements the public methods or how you manipulate your properties—when you must (provide).**

Abstract *relieves* you of **how it implements**

For abstract classes, you shouldn't provide any implementation, only that it would have such parameters or it would have such functions with such signatures. However an abstract class **is** compilable on its own. Because you don't need to provide anything more than that.

Comment: That such a great explanation related to Swift field!